# How do you copy the value from one cell in one worksheets to two cells in consecutive rows in another worksheet by dragging down?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you copy the value from one cell in one worksheets to two cells in consecutive rows in another worksheet by dragging down?

Example:

Worksheet 1:

```
1
2
3
```

Worksheet 2:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's other ways, but here's a couple ways you can use a formula:

---

**Method 1 - Copy + helper column**

1 - Copy the column from Worksheet 1 to Worksheet 2.
2 - Put this formula in the first cell of the adjacent column in Worksheet 2. (Assuming your data starts in A1, this would go in B1.)

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",ROUNDUP(ROWS($B$1:B1)/2,0)))
```

Note: If your data resides in different columns, adjust the column references accordingly. If it starts in a lower row, you'll need to adjust the row references *and* put `+x` after `ROUNDUP(ROWS($B$1:B1)/2,0)` - where `x` is the offset from row 1.

Example for data starting in C5, and the "helper column" (where the formula goes) starts at D5:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",ROUNDUP(ROWS($D$5:D5)/2,0)+4))
```

3 - Copy the formula down for twice as many rows as are populated in the original data set.

---

**Method 2 - Reference from the other sheet.**

Same as method 1, but without the initial column copy. Below formula assumes your data starts in A1 of Sheet1 and you're dropping it starting at A1 of Sheet2. Adjust accordingly for position offsets and differences in sheet names.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Sheet1'!A",ROUNDUP(ROWS($A$1:A1)/2,0)))
```

Drop that in A1 of Sheet2 and copy it down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but with both methods I receive a 'this formula contains an error' message. Is the formula correct?

Comment: All formulas are correct - the first and third are cut-and-paste directly from my test sheet in Excel. For a moment, I thought the second one was missing a parenthesis at the end, but turns out it was right the first time too. Perhaps paste your formula in here and we can sort it out.